# I keep getting this error in sails for firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, sails.js

I have a sails and node app ,i am using firebase to push notification on that app
The issue I keep getting is that

```
The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services
```

my code in app.js file

```
  sails = require('sails');
  rc = require('sails/accessible/rc');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "my url"
    });
    // Start server
  sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

I have tried some solution for the file that depend on that service by using setTimeOut to delay calling a specific require file and this actually help me on some cases but I want a solution so that I don't have to do this work around

Answer (score 1):

For initializing your firebase admin I prefer to add it to `config/bootstrap.js` file as global variable (without const or var), so you can access it in all over your application

**Note** sails runs bootstrap file once the app started, so you can write any piece of code you'd like to run in each time you start the project

example

```
admin = require('firebase-admin');
serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "my url"
});
```

you can also define firestore, auth, bucket, etc,,

```
auth = admin.auth();
bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
```

now in any of your controllers you can use firestore just by

```
await db.collection('user').doc('userId').set({})
```